# Leaflet- add and remove all layers in list based on variable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

first let me state I am not very good at Javascript and I have a feeling this is a simple formatting matter.

I am trying to add and remove layers to a map based on a variable; in this case **num**. I have functions that add or remove to **num** based on clicks.

I can add and remove one layer easily with the if statements in the below code. what I would like to do is build a list of layers and then iterate through them and to add or remove them from the map.

this is what I have

```
 var one = [Township,Section] \\list of layers
 for (i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
  if (num != 1 && map.hasLayer(i)) {
    map.removeLayer(i);
  }
  if (num == 1 && map.hasLayer(i) == false)
    {
      map.addLayer(i);
    }
  }
```

The If statement works fine with one layer (without for statement) but I cannot get it to run through all layers in the list one.

if anyone has any thoughts I would appriciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i is an integer value, not a layer. So `map.hasLayer(i)` and `map.removeLayer(i)` takes wrong type of parameter. Try to use `map.hasLayer(one[i])` and `map.removeLayer(one[i])`

EDIT: Also `map.addLayer(one[i])`